# DayOfWeek yesterday swedish

Tags: c#, weekday

I cant figure how to get the yesterday string to swedish culture

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string today = dateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString();
string yesterday = dateTime.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek.ToString(); //Fetch day i.e. Mon, Tues
```

I have got culture working for todays day, but not yesterday

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE");
var day = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
```

Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use either the `ddd` or `dddd` [custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dddSpecifier) with the `ToString(string, IFormatProvider)` method.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE");
string today = dateTime.ToString("ddd", culture);
string yesterday = dateTime.AddDays(-1).ToString("ddd", culture);
```